# Typescript: selective properties copying between two instances produces a compilation error

Tags: typescript

The following code snippet:

```js
interface Foo {
    acceptString?: (arg: string) => void;
    acceptNumber?: (arg: number) => void;
}

function copyFoo(foo: Foo, keys: ReadonlyArray<keyof Foo>): Foo {
    const copy: Foo = {};

    for (const key of keys) {
        copy[key] = foo[key]; // error: foo[key] isn't assignable to copy[key]
    }

    return copy;
}
```

produces the compilation error:

```
Type '((arg: string) => void) | ((arg: number) => void) | undefined' is not assignable to type '(((arg: string) => void) & ((arg: number) => void)) | undefined'. 
  Type '(arg: string) => void' is not assignable to type '((arg: string) => void) & ((arg: number) => void)'.
    Type '(arg: string) => void' is not assignable to type '(arg: number) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'arg' and 'arg' are incompatible.
        Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

It's a simplified example that only demonstrates the problem. Actually the code is correct,`foo[key]` and `copy[key]` have the same type because I use the same key, but the compiler doesn't know that. Can I get rid of the error without type casting?

[Typescript playground snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=6&ssc=10&pln=6&pc=17#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRyiSADmAMphSgDmA-AFzIAUcUdLAzjfQJTIAvAD5kAN3TAAJgG4CxEgnJgAcgFcAtgCNozNhy7IQW3VEGiJUuQQC+BAjHUgEYYOhDIE6MgE8M6KwwmCwBADTIANYQvtwsAEoQcNIeADa+AIJQUHC+ADzRvugwaJgi-KGYOArE3iC8Xj6+lVhCOLby+DVEwVBsdQ2FyMVRMdyCeISKtU0A2oUAusLIwejzMQudivZdU0RQEGDqUJ7efp07QA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is not that smart at narrowing types inside loops. To avoid a cast, you could wrap the assignment inside a helper function.

```
function copyFoo(foo: Foo, keys: ReadonlyArray<keyof Foo>): Foo {
    const copy: Foo = {};

    for (const key of keys) {
        copyProp(copy, key, foo[key]);
    }

    return copy;
}

function copyProp<K extends keyof Foo>(copy: Foo, key: K, value: typeof copy[K]) {
    copy[key] = value;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHKJIAOYAymFKAOYD8AXMgBRxQ1MDOVtAlMgF4AfMgBu6YABMA3PkLEIZAHIBXALYAjaIxZsOyEOq1R+wsRJm4AvrlwwVIBGGDoQyBOhIBPDOmYxMJl8AGmQAawgvTiYAJQg4SVcAGy8AQSgoOC8AHgivdBg0TCFeIMwcOQIPEG53Ty8yrAEcK1lK5ACoFmravOQC8MjOfjxCMbrvAAUoT2YPb1C80ID0AG08gF1eWTGbdqgIMBUoN3mvWT37R2dXCa9pz2yAaWQIAA9IEElOQfzC3yEc3qjUWkSYT1CojgSRUECYYC8JAgAzOqyeWwqY1Rm0EYmhsIuuCAA)